# Rails will_paginate shows duplicates on HABTM models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I'm using will_paginate with a HABTM relationship between Blog Posts and Tags. Whenever I apply pagination, I get duplicate posts shown because the HABTM in Rails doesn't keep the database unique, it applies the uniqueness upon making the query.

blog_posts.rb

`has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, :uniq => true`

tag.rb

`has_and_belongs_to_many :blog_posts, :uniq => true`

Per the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M002126) for ActiveRecord, :uniq does not prevent duplicate relationships being stored, it just ignores them when building the query.

Here is the issue:
`tag = Tag.find(1)`
`tag.blog_posts.count` equals 1, but:
`tag.blog_posts.page(nil).count` equals 3, and all 3 are duplicates of the same post. The correct behavior should be to show only 1, not duplicated.

I know I could just copy the SQL queries that are being generated here and fix it that way, but that doesn't seem to be a good solution. Could someone help me fix the underlying problem? (though I'm concerned it's a bug in will_paginate)

**Edit:** This appears to be an issue with Kaminari as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I ran into this problem before. Try adding this to your query:

```
.group("id")
```

It's not a bug in will_paginate, because all that does is take the data it gives you and paginates it in the view. The solution lies in the data you provide it.

Comment: This works! But I disagree, I think it is a bug. will_paginate is ignoring the specifications of ActiveRecord. Things work without will_paginate, they don't work with it because it changes the normal ActiveRecord SQL query, and you have to go out of your way to make things work. Thanks a lot for the solution!!!

Comment: Yes thanks Ultimation - agree that this could be considered a bug or at least an improvement for will_paginate